# Error compiling Xamarin Application on Release mode: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Error only occurs when compiling on release mode... on debug mode the compiling occurs without problem... can you help me?

This is the stack trace for error...

```
en System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
en MonoDroid.Tuner.PreserveApplications.PreserveTypeProperty(CustomAttribute attribute, String property)
en MonoDroid.Tuner.PreserveApplications.ProcessAttributeProvider(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
en MonoDroid.Tuner.PreserveApplications.ProcessAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
en Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.DispatchAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
en Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.BrowseAssemblies(IEnumerable`1 assemblies)
en Mono.Tuner.SubStepDispatcher.Process(LinkContext context)
en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
en Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
en MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
en Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
en Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() en /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:línea 17 AppMsMovil.Android 5 Compilación
```

[This is my Android Options...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsZqG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your linker settings? Please change it to None, then release it, if you will get the same exception,then please share Android option screenshot that contains all the settings when release.
No Dex compiler was specified, select D8 Dex compiler in the Android project properties => android options => dex compiler D8
Code :

d8

Comment: Thanks Amjad. I changed the Linker option to none, and the eror changes to this. 
Error  java/lang/String;)I: defining a static interface method requires --min-sdk-version >= 24 (currently 13) for interface methods: androidx.constraintlayout.core.motion.utils.TypedValues$Attributes.getId : (Ljava/lang/String;)I AppMsMovil.Android 5   Compilación

Comment: I upload the "Android Options" configuration Page.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Did it work????

Comment: Please change dex compiler D8 instead of dx

Comment: I needed to remove ProGuard option, cuz it doesnt be compatible with D8 Compiler dex but... it looks that works... Thanks!