# After installing my .apk won't load on my phone

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm trying to make Android app using Visual Studio and Xamarin. I've signed the app with a sign which I've created (it's on release mode). I've installed this apk on my phone (sign via Ad Hoc, then I download the .apk file and then I installed it) and this is ok, but when I open the app all I see is blank space. It doesn't even show that app is running. When I was debugging using my phone instead of emulator it was working just fine.

Does anyone know what's causing it and how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried deploying directly to the phone from VS in Release mode?  Have you checked the device logs for any relevant messages?

Comment: Tried it and it gives me this error:    Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.PreserveApplications.PreserveTypeProperty(CustomAttribute attribute, String property)

Comment: I have a feeling that I broke it even more. Last time I could archive it without problems but now I can't even do that. This time the error is Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void AndroidX.RecyclerView.Widget.RecyclerView/
LayoutManager::n_OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo_Landroidx_recyclerview_widget_RecyclerView_Recycler_Landroidx_recyclerview_widget_RecyclerView_State_Landroidx_core_view_accessibility_AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat_(System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr,System.IntPtr)' in assembly: 'Xamarin.AndroidX.RecyclerView.dll' ...

Comment: Not able to archive is a different problem. Get to a clean state: Reboot pc. Delete bin and obj folders in solution. Rebuild Solution. THEN archive.

Comment: ... Manually delete app from device.

Comment: After deleting bin obj folders rebuild gives me again error:    System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 predicate) at MonoDroid.Tuner.PreserveApplications.PreserveTypeProperty(CustomAttribute attribute, String property)

Comment: You can check the [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70963556/error-compiling-xamarin-application-on-release-mode-system-invalidoperationexce) which has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It works. I had to set linking to None, dex compiler as d8 and update some Xamarin nugets.